# how to filter post by title using Vue js 2.x directives instead of vue js 1.x

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am learning to use vue js with wprest api by following [watch-learn tutorials](http://watch-learn.com/video-tutorials/theming-with-wp-rest-api-part-05-filter-posts-by-title) on the same topic. the problem is that the vue js version used in the tutorial seems to be v 1.x and i started using vue js 2.x. I was able to figure out the initial stages on how to display all the post using vue js 2.x.. I have an input field using which I search for a specific title it should filter and show the post. The issue is unable to workout exactly how it needs to be computed using vuejs 2.x.. I have included a codepen link containing the json data as well as my working code.

the following is the input field to be used to filter the posts by title

```
<div class="row">
    <h4>Filter by name:</h4>
    <input type="text" name="" v-model="nameFilter">
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" v-for="post in posts">
        <div class="card post">
            <img class="card-img-top" v-bind:src="post.fi_300x180" >
            <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-text">{{ post.title.rendered }}</h2>
                <small class="tags" v-for="category in post.cats">{{ category.name }}</small>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- .post -->
    </div> <!-- .col-md-4 -->
</div> <!-- .row -->
```

https://codepen.io/dhivyasolomon/pen/LdZKJY

I would appreciate any help in figuring out the next step. thanks.

Comment: You were close. You need to v-for over the `filteredPost` computed vlaue, and you need to update `filteredPost` to use `nameFilter`. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/VXjozb?editors=1010

Comment: awesome thanks for the quick reply. one tiny issue is the filter seems to be case sensitive . Like if i type 'what is lorem ipsum' instead of 'What is Lorem Ipsum' it doesnt display the post. is it possible to fix that

Comment: Yes, you just need to update the computed filter. I modified the above pen to ignore case.

Comment: awesome thanks for quick response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need directives, achieve this using the power of [Computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

So you will have to itarate over the computed property which filter the posts by the input value and return a new array of posts.

Little example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  computed: {
    filteredPosts () {
      return this.posts.filter(p => p.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.filterText.toLowerCase()))
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      filterText: '',
      posts: [
        {
          title: 'My first post title',
          body: 'foo'
        },
        {
          title: 'Another post title',
          body: 'foo'
        },
        {
          title: 'This will work fine',
          body: 'foo'
        },
        {
          title: 'Omg it\'s working!',
          body: 'foo'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.15/vue.js"></script>


<div id="example">
  
  <input type="text" v-model="filterText" />
  
  <ul>
    <li v-for="post in filteredPosts">{{ post.title }}</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```